# How to remove duplication in git tree from git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am using git-svn to track a canonical subversion repository.  My local repository had the commits from the svn, but also additional branches that I was working on concurrently, that were *not* in the subversion respository.

My old computer died, and so I'm trying to duplicate that setup on my new computer.  Luckily I backed up my git repository to a server, which I can clone from to get all of my git commits (including the ones not part of the SVN).  However, this tree cannot interact with git-svn because it doesn't have the right metadata.  I also can use git-svn to init a /new/ git tree which matches the SVN commits, but git-svn creates a duplicate tree that is unconnected from the rest of my git commits.  This means that I cannot simply use the new tree, because I would lose all git commits that aren't a part of the SVN.

In short, my tree looks like this:

`A D   A'
|/    |
B E   B'
|/    |
C     C'`

where ABC are the git-svn commits from my old computer, A'B'C' are the duplicate commits that git-svn creates on my new computer, and DE are various commits that only exist in the git repository from the old computer (they are not part of the SVN).

How can I deduplicate these trees, so that I get a single tree with the extra commits properly attached, and that will interact with the svn repository properly?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

#### A. git-svn repo <- git repo

You could add the local repository from the old computer as a *remote* in the newly create *git-svn* repository. From there, you can simply import you old branches by simply fetching them:

From the *git-svn* repo you could do:

```
git remote add backup C:\path\to\local\repo
git fetch backup
git checkout -t backup/your-old-branch
git remote remove backup
```

Since the commits' SHA-1 hashes are *unique across different copies of the same repository* your old local branches should still be based on top of the same commits in the newly initialized *git-svn* repository.

#### B. git repo <- git-svn repo

Another solution would be to add the *git-svn* metadata to the local repository from the old computer and then fetch any new commits from the SVN server.

From the *local* repo you could do:

```
git svn init <svn-repo-url>
git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/heads/master
git checkout master
git svn rebase
```

The second command makes sure that the `git-svn` reference points to the tip of the local `master` branch. Then, `git svn rebase` will fetch any new commits from the SVN repository and update the local `master` branch.

Comment: I double checked, and that's not the case for my repository. I have two copies of the same commit with different SHA-1 Hashes.  It looks like this is caused by there being "merge" commits in my tree.  So from git's perspective there is a merge, but from SVN perspective it doesn't know about the merge, and so it is treated as a linear commit.   This causes the merge commit and all subsequent commits to be duplicated regardless of how I instantiate the repository.

Comment: In that case you can rebase your old branch on top of the right commit in the _git-svn_ repo using `git rebase --onto`. See my updated answer.

Comment: This turns into a huge mess of rebasing all my local branches off of rebased versions of each other.

Comment: It also results in me losing the information about which branches were merged.  Because everything is rebased on top of the svn "fake merge" commits, all of the merged branches appear to be dangling.

Comment: Did you merge your local branches into a branch tracked by `git-svn` or the other way around?

Comment: Furthermore, rebasing doesn't appear to produce commits with the same sha-1 hashes.  This means I essentially need to manually graft every single branch onto the git-svn tree using rebase.

Comment: I merged the local branches onto the branch tracked by git-svn